# I'm trying to randomise four variables but nothing seems to happen

Tags: java, loops

So I'm trying to do this code where it displays matches for a tournament. I want to make it so every time you run the program it randomises the teams order and I tried to make it so no duplicates can be created. I have four variables to use. When I run it, nothing seems to happen, it doesn't crash, it just shows that it is working but nothing gets displayed.

```
public void generateMatches() {
    w = (int)(Math.random()*3);
    x = (int)(Math.random()*3);
    y = (int)(Math.random()*3);
    z = (int)(Math.random()*3);
    do {                   
        w = (int)(Math.random()*3);
        x = (int)(Math.random()*3);
        y = (int)(Math.random()*3);
        z = (int)(Math.random()*3);
    } while (x == y || y == z || x == z || x == w || y == w || z == w);
}
```

Comment: Where do you display anything in that code?

Comment: It crash or doesn't crash the JVM?

Comment: Your problem description ("it doesn't crash") contradicts your title ("it just crashes").  Which is it? Also @Kayaman is right.  You need to edit your question to clarify it, resolve ambiguities and contradictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The do-while loop never ends because your condition is always `true`. It can never be `false` because the output of `(Math.random() * 3)` is 0, 1 or 2. Therefore, you can never produce 4 distinct numbers with your approach.

---

One solution is to create a list with the possible numbers, shuffle it and get the individual entries to make the assignments to your variables:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
Collections.shuffle(list);
w = list.get(0);
x = list.get(1);
y = list.get(2);
z = list.get(3);
```

Comment: I totally forgot about `Collections#shuffle`. Nice solution.